# Boot taking forever with a 106 JBOD attached. - WARNING: Device /dev/xxx not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, udev

When attaching a 106 JBOD enclosures (106 18TB drives via HBA card) to a Debian Bullseye server, I get spammed with the following for each path to any of the 106 drives.

It makes a reboot take a huge amount of time.

Example:

```
WARNING: Device /dev/sdcf not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds
```

[image]

What is causing this? I seem unable to figure out.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to systemd/udev.

The solution is installing systemd and udev version 250.3-2~bpo11+1 or newer from backports and reboot, this works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems on my targets. But, On Debian 11.5 with systemd 251.5-1, not possible for me to change the behaviour.

In my LVM log, always following messages

> WARNING: Device /dev/sda17 not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds.

Solution for me was to change behaviour of LVM by setting **udev_sync** and **udev_rules** to 0 instead of Debian standard value to 1.

Please find bellow my configuration.

```
$ cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf |grep -v "#" |grep -v ^$


config {
    checks = 1
    abort_on_errors = 0
    profile_dir = "/etc/lvm/profile"
}
devices {
    dir = "/dev"
    scan = [ "/dev" ]
    obtain_device_list_from_udev = 1
    external_device_info_source = "none"
    cache_dir = "/run/lvm"
    cache_file_prefix = ""
    write_cache_state = 1
    sysfs_scan = 1
    multipath_component_detection = 1
    md_component_detection = 1
    fw_raid_component_detection = 0
    md_chunk_alignment = 1
    data_alignment_detection = 1
    data_alignment = 0
    data_alignment_offset_detection = 1
    ignore_suspended_devices = 0
    ignore_lvm_mirrors = 1
    disable_after_error_count = 0
    require_restorefile_with_uuid = 1
    pv_min_size = 2048
    issue_discards = 0
    allow_changes_with_duplicate_pvs = 0
}
allocation {
    maximise_cling = 1
    use_blkid_wiping = 1
    wipe_signatures_when_zeroing_new_lvs = 1
    mirror_logs_require_separate_pvs = 0
    cache_pool_metadata_require_separate_pvs = 0
    thin_pool_metadata_require_separate_pvs = 0
}
log {
    report_command_log = 1
    command_log_sort = "log_seq_num"
    command_log_cols = "log_seq_num,log_type,log_context,log_object_type,log_object_name,log_object_id,log_object_group,log_object_group_id,log_message,log_errno,log_ret_code"
    verbose = 0
    silent = 0
    syslog = 0
    file = "/var/log/lvm/lvm.log"
    overwrite = 0
    level = 5
    indent = 1
    command_names = 0
    prefix = "  "
    activation = 0
    debug_classes = [ "memory", "devices", "activation", "allocation", "metadata", "cache", "locking", "lvmpolld", "dbus" ]
}
backup {
    backup = 1
    backup_dir = "/etc/lvm/backup"
    archive = 1
    archive_dir = "/etc/lvm/archive"
    retain_min = 10
    retain_days = 30
}
shell {
    history_size = 100
}
global {
    umask = 077
    test = 0
    units = "h"
    si_unit_consistency = 1
    suffix = 1
    activation = 1
    fallback_to_lvm1 = 0
    format = "lvm2"
    proc = "/proc"
    etc = "/etc"
    locking_type = 1
    wait_for_locks = 1
    fallback_to_clustered_locking = 1
    fallback_to_local_locking = 1
    locking_dir = "/run/lock/lvm"
    prioritise_write_locks = 1
    abort_on_internal_errors = 0
    detect_internal_vg_cache_corruption = 0
    metadata_read_only = 0
    mirror_segtype_default = "raid1"
    raid10_segtype_default = "raid10"
    sparse_segtype_default = "thin"
    use_lvmetad = 1
    lvmetad_update_wait_time = 10
    use_lvmlockd = 0
    lvmlockd_lock_retries = 3
    system_id_source = "none"
    use_lvmpolld = 1
    notify_dbus = 1
}
activation {
    checks = 0
    udev_sync = 0
        udev_rules = 0
    verify_udev_operations = 0
    retry_deactivation = 1
    missing_stripe_filler = "error"
    use_linear_target = 1
    reserved_stack = 64
    reserved_memory = 8192
    process_priority = -18
    raid_region_size = 512
    readahead = "auto"
    raid_fault_policy = "warn"
    mirror_image_fault_policy = "remove"
    mirror_log_fault_policy = "allocate"
    snapshot_autoextend_threshold = 100
    snapshot_autoextend_percent = 20
    thin_pool_autoextend_threshold = 100
    thin_pool_autoextend_percent = 20
    use_mlockall = 0
    monitoring = 1
    polling_interval = 15
    activation_mode = "degraded"
}
report {
    output_format = "basic"
    compact_output = 0
    compact_output_cols = ""
    aligned = 1
    buffered = 1
    separator = " "
    list_item_separator = ","
    prefixes = 0
    quoted = 1
    binary_values_as_numeric = 0
    time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %T %z"
    devtypes_sort = "devtype_name"
    devtypes_cols = "devtype_name,devtype_max_partitions,devtype_description"
    devtypes_cols_verbose = "devtype_name,devtype_max_partitions,devtype_description"
    lvs_sort = "vg_name,lv_name"
    lvs_cols = "lv_name,vg_name,lv_attr,lv_size,pool_lv,origin,data_percent,metadata_percent,move_pv,mirror_log,copy_percent,convert_lv"
    lvs_cols_verbose = "lv_name,vg_name,seg_count,lv_attr,lv_size,lv_major,lv_minor,lv_kernel_major,lv_kernel_minor,pool_lv,origin,data_percent,metadata_percent,move_pv,copy_percent,mirror_log,convert_lv,lv_uuid,lv_profile"
    vgs_cols = "vg_name,pv_count,lv_count,snap_count,vg_attr,vg_size,vg_free"
    vgs_cols_verbose = "vg_name,vg_attr,vg_extent_size,pv_count,lv_count,snap_count,vg_size,vg_free,vg_uuid,vg_profile"
    pvs_sort = "pv_name"
    pvs_cols = "pv_name,vg_name,pv_fmt,pv_attr,pv_size,pv_free"
    pvs_cols_verbose = "pv_name,vg_name,pv_fmt,pv_attr,pv_size,pv_free,dev_size,pv_uuid"
    segs_sort = "vg_name,lv_name,seg_start"
    segs_cols = "lv_name,vg_name,lv_attr,stripes,segtype,seg_size"
    segs_cols_verbose = "lv_name,vg_name,lv_attr,seg_start,seg_size,stripes,segtype,stripesize,chunksize"
    pvsegs_sort = "pv_name,pvseg_start"
    pvsegs_cols = "pv_name,vg_name,pv_fmt,pv_attr,pv_size,pv_free,pvseg_start,pvseg_size"
    pvsegs_cols_verbose = "pv_name,vg_name,pv_fmt,pv_attr,pv_size,pv_free,pvseg_start,pvseg_size,lv_name,seg_start_pe,segtype,seg_pe_ranges"
    vgs_cols_full = "vg_all"
    pvs_cols_full = "pv_all"
    lvs_cols_full = "lv_all"
    pvsegs_cols_full = "pvseg_all,pv_uuid,lv_uuid"
    segs_cols_full = "seg_all,lv_uuid"
    vgs_sort_full = "vg_name"
    pvs_sort_full = "pv_name"
    lvs_sort_full = "vg_name,lv_name"
    pvsegs_sort_full = "pv_uuid,pvseg_start"
    segs_sort_full = "lv_uuid,seg_start"
    mark_hidden_devices = 1
    two_word_unknown_device = 0
}
dmeventd {
    mirror_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2mirror.so"
    raid_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2raid.so"
    snapshot_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2snapshot.so"
    thin_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so"
    executable = "/sbin/dmeventd"
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a comment and does not help the OP with any solution. Please revise or delete.

Comment: @number9 answer is updated.